# Drawing a rotating sphere by using a pixel shader in Direct3D

Tags: math, mapping, shader, direct3d, hlsl

I would like to draw a textured circle in Direct3D which looks like a real 3D sphere. For this purpose, I took a [texture](http://www.sharecg.com/v/12975) of a billard ball and tried to write a pixel shader in `HLSL`, which maps it onto a simple pre-transformed quad in such a way that it looks like a 3-dimensional sphere (apart from the lighting, of course).

This is what I've got so far:

```
struct PS_INPUT
{
    float2 Texture : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct PS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

sampler2D Tex0;

// main function
PS_OUTPUT ps_main( PS_INPUT In )
{
    // default color for points outside the sphere (alpha=0, i.e. invisible)
    PS_OUTPUT Out; 
    Out.Color = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);  

    float pi = acos(-1);    

    // map texel coordinates to [-1, 1]
    float x = 2.0 * (In.Texture.x - 0.5);
    float y = 2.0 * (In.Texture.y - 0.5);
    float r = sqrt(x * x + y * y);    

    // if the texel is not inside the sphere
    if(r > 1.0f)
      return Out;

    // 3D position on the front half of the sphere
    float p[3] = {x, y, sqrt(1 - x*x + y*y)};

    // calculate UV mapping
    float u = 0.5 + atan2(p[2], p[0]) / (2.0*pi);
    float v = 0.5 - asin(p[1]) / pi;   

    // do some simple antialiasing
    float alpha = saturate((1-r) * 32); // scale by half quad width
    Out.Color = tex2D(Tex0, float2(u, v));  
    Out.Color.a = alpha;  

    return Out;
}
```

The texture coordinates of my quad range from 0 to 1, so I first map them to [-1, 1]. After that I followed the formula in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping#Finding_UV_on_a_sphere) to calculate the correct texture coordinates for the current point.

At first, the outcome looked ok, but I'd like to be able to rotate this illusion of a sphere arbitrarily. So I gradually increased `u` in the hope of rotating the sphere around the vertical axis. This is the result:

[image: rotating billard ball]

As you can see, the imprint of the ball looks unnaturally deformed when it reaches the edge. Can anyone see any reason for this? And additionally, how could I implement rotations around an arbitrary axis?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the mistake by myself: The calculation of the `z` value which corresponds to the current point `(x, y)` on the front half of the sphere was wrong. It must of course be:

[image: z on a unit sphere]

That's all, it works as exspected now. Furthermore, I figured out how to rotate the sphere. You just have to rotate the point `p` before calculating `u` and `v` by multiplying it with a 3D rotation matrix like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) for example.

The result looks like the following:

[image: rotating billard ball]

If anyone has any advice as to how I could smooth the texture a litte bit, please leave a comment.